# Saving String to Settings File System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection Not Working

Tags: vb.net

Using VS2017.  When I call a PrintDialog button, I want to save some data to the Users Settings file.  But of course I do not want any repeat data in the file.  The following works, but only when I close the App, I want it to run at DialogResult.Yes;

```
...
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then ' Save the entered data and continue the print
        'MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbPayToo.Text) Or Me.cbPayToo.Text = "" Then
            If Not cbPayToo.Items.Contains(cbPayToo.Text) Then 'make sure the item to save does not exist
                Dim strings(cbPayToo.Items.Count - 1) As String
                cbPayToo.Items.CopyTo(strings, 0)
                My.Settings.cbPayToo.Insert(0, cbPayToo.Text)
            End If
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbCheckAmount.Text) Or Me.cbCheckAmount.Text = "" Then
            If Not cbCheckAmount.Items.Contains(strCheckAmount) Then 'make sure the item to save does not exist
                Dim strings(cbCheckAmount.Items.Count - 1) As String
                cbCheckAmount.Items.CopyTo(strings, 0)
                My.Settings.cbCheckAmount.Insert(0, strCheckAmount)
            End If
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbMemoBox.Text) Or Me.cbMemoBox.Text = "" Then
            If Not cbMemoBox.Items.Contains(cbMemoBox.Text) Then 'make sure the item to save does not exist
                Dim strings(cbMemoBox.Items.Count - 1) As String
                cbMemoBox.Items.CopyTo(strings, 0)
                My.Settings.cbMemoBox.Insert(0, cbMemoBox.Text)
            End If
        End If
    ....
    End If
```

I run this when I close the installed App, and it will write to Settings properly;

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    My.Settings.DateBox = DateBox.Location
    My.Settings.CheckToName = cbPayToo.Location
    My.Settings.DollarAmount = cbCheckAmount.Location
    My.Settings.pbSig = pbSig.ImageLocation
    My.Settings.MemoBox = cbMemoBox.Location
End Sub
```

What is odd is that when I run FormClosing, the Settings file is updated with the cb data.  Can I not update the Settings file during runtime?

Comment: Make `My.Settings.Save()` the last line of your FormClosing method.

Comment: @LArsTech "The following works, but only when I close the App", he already saves it on close, all you would do with that is save twice on close, he wants to save also on other than closing.

Comment: After all the bunch of if statements, use `My.Settings.Save()`

Answer (score 1):

It is because in your project settings>application you have checked "save my.settings on shutdown".

Add this to save it manually.

```
My.Settings.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

After all the if statements, save the settings:

```
 ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then ' Save the entered data and continue the print
    'MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbPayToo.Text) Or Me.cbPayToo.Text = "" Then
        If Not cbPayToo.Items.Contains(cbPayToo.Text) Then 'make sure the item to save does not exist
            Dim strings(cbPayToo.Items.Count - 1) As String
            cbPayToo.Items.CopyTo(strings, 0)
            My.Settings.cbPayToo.Insert(0, cbPayToo.Text)
        End If
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbCheckAmount.Text) Or Me.cbCheckAmount.Text = "" Then
        If Not cbCheckAmount.Items.Contains(strCheckAmount) Then 'make sure the item to save does not exist
            Dim strings(cbCheckAmount.Items.Count - 1) As String
            cbCheckAmount.Items.CopyTo(strings, 0)
            My.Settings.cbCheckAmount.Insert(0, strCheckAmount)
        End If
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbMemoBox.Text) Or Me.cbMemoBox.Text = "" Then
        If Not cbMemoBox.Items.Contains(cbMemoBox.Text) Then 'make sure the item to save does not exist
            Dim strings(cbMemoBox.Items.Count - 1) As String
            cbMemoBox.Items.CopyTo(strings, 0)
            My.Settings.cbMemoBox.Insert(0, cbMemoBox.Text)
        End If
    End If
    'Add this line to save the settings Immediately
    My.Settings.Save()
    'To update the settings without saving them , you can use My.Settings.Update()
....
End If
```